# Error: Must use destructuring state assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Do you have any idea this error? I am getting ESlint error for the following line visible={this.state.visible}

It says: "Must use destructuring state assignment"

It uses: "eslint-config-airbnb"

Thank you in advance

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd'

class EditProfile extends React.Component {
  state = { visible: false }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    })
  }

  handleOk = e => {
    console.log(e)
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    })
  }

  handleCancel = e => {
    console.log(e)
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Modal Card
        </Button>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          footer={null}
          className="custom-modal-v1"
          centered
        >
          Text
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default EditProfile
```

Comment: Probably expect you to do... `const { visible } = this.state;` in your render function.

Comment: This is a ESLint plugin rule: [`react/destructuring-assignment`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) used by _eslint-config-airbnb_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your render function to this and then access visible directly.
This is es6 destructing where you can extract key as a variable with same name.
read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
      render() {
          const { visible } = this.state; // destructing visible form state
          return (
              <div>
                  <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
                      Modal Card
                  </Button>
                  <Modal
                      visible={visible}
                      onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                      footer={null}
                      className="custom-modal-v1"
                      centered
                  >
                      Text
                  </Modal>
              </div>
         )
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to destructure the value from the state rather than using it like `this.state.visible`. Just use the state value like this

```
  render() {
   //Destructure value from state
   const { visible } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
          Modal Card
        </Button>
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          footer={null}
          className="custom-modal-v1"
          centered
        >
          Text
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Hope this helps !